# CS50 Retrieving blank images when writing program to recover jpgs

Tags: c, cs50

I am having trouble identifying why I am getting blank images when recovering jps for an assignment in CS50. I read the entire file, write whenever the start of a jpg file is found, and close whenever the end of a jpg file is found. I create the total of 50 images, but all of them are blank. Could someone help push me in the right direction?
This is my code:

```
const int BLOCK = 512;

    uint8_t buffer[BLOCK];
    char filename[50][8] = { };
    int counter = 0;
    while (fread(buffer, BLOCK, 1, input) == 1)
    {
        sprintf(&filename[counter][0], "%03i.jpg", counter);
        FILE *img = fopen(&filename[counter][0], "w");
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer [2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if ((buffer[511] & 0xf0) != 0xe0)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, BLOCK, 1, img);
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
            }
        }
    }
```

I made the update here:

```
while (fread(buffer, BLOCK, 1, input) == 1)
    {
        sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
        FILE *img = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer [2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if ((buffer[511] & 0xf0) != 0xe0)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, BLOCK, 1, img);
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `counter++` for each block? I think you should examine the logic. You open a new file in every loop, but you never check anything, (or for array overflow).

Comment: Not sure how your logic is supposed to work but: (1) shouldn't the `counter++;` line be in the same block as the `fclose(img);` line? (2) Shouldn't you be writing the buffer even if the end-marker is found? (3) Are you sure each component file is an exact multiple of 512 bytes (maybe I'm being dumb, on that one)?

Comment: @AdrianMole I wondered about the EOF marker too. There is no requirement that a jpeg be a multiple of 512 bytes, but each allegedly lost sector might be.

Comment: There is no need to have memory for more than 1 filename at a time. If you reach the end of your input file, you don't close the output file. You open a new file for each block you read even if there is not JPEG header found. If you read the second (or any following) block of a picture, you don't write. The logic is totally bokren. You should check the video again that describes what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Most people approach this problem by detecting the *start* of the new file, and closing the previous, opening the new file, before writing the block. The EOF marker isn't much help. The final block is detected because `fread` returned `0`, after which the current file must be closed.

Comment: `if ((buffer[511] & 0xf0) != 0xe0)` where did you get that?

Comment: @AdrianMole 
1. We are told to keep count of how many jpgs we find.
2. I assumed my code was essentially writing every block found if the conditions were met, is that not the case?
3. They tell us that they are in x number of 512 byte blocks and that we should search 512 byte blocks, 1 at a time.

Comment: @Gerhardh When I tried renaming the string everytime using sprintf, it would just create one jpg for some reason. I will close the file. Would a while loop work instead of an if condition to write until end of JPEG?

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean by never check for anything?

Comment: You already have a `while` loop that reads following blocks. You just need to handle them correctly. That condition is completely wrong. There is no requirement to have that nibble in last byte of a block.

Comment: You don't check that `fopen` succeeds, nor if your (unnecessary) array overflows, which it very might do because of the faulty positioning of `counter++` and the opening of a new file for every block.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary array and switched the counter++ position. I am still getting the same result. Is the problem the fact that I’m not writing into the files that I am opening?

Comment: You still have that strange condition which prevents you from writing most of your data. Also you don't write anything for block 2-n for any JPG. As a side not your should open your file in binary mode. Step through your code in a debugger and check these scenarious: Read a block before you found any JPG header. Read a block with JPG header for the first time. Read block 2-n of that JPG file. Read block with JPG header after you already found one earliery. Reach end of file while you had found a JPG header. Reach end of file before you found any JPG header.

Comment: You might first write down what has to happen in each of that cases and compare with what your code does.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you so much! I could not have done it without you. What clicked was when you said I was not writing anything in the second block.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much as well! what I did is I previously declared the FILE *img; and until later did I do the fopen, I had understood that I had to do them both at the same time. I also changed the counter++ positions and added some other paths to the ifs.

Comment: @Gerhardh @ WeatherVane it would be great if you could provide some further feedback to know what you both would do differently, so that I may learn and make better code in the future! I will update the question with my final submitted code at the end.

Comment: You could post a self-answer. It's better not to change the code in the question that was asked.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh okay, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

This question is now solved. My whole logic was flawed and I wasnt writing anything, I was just opening files. Bellow is my reworked code, its funny how overnight everything just clicked and was able to write it in like 10 minutes!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int BLOCK = 512;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover card.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t buffer[BLOCK];
    char filename[8] = { };
    int counter = 0;
    FILE *img;
    while (fread(buffer, BLOCK, 1, input) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer [2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, BLOCK, 1, img);
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, BLOCK, 1, img);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else if (counter != 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, BLOCK, 1, img);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(img);
}
```

Comment: You could shorten/simplify  the code a little by having only one `fwrite` at the bottom of the while loop (it's always needed), and just one `counter++` at the bottom of the "start detected" block (cos that's always done there). That leaves one empty code block, so you could just change its condition to `if (counter != 0)` or the idiomatic `if (counter)`.

Comment: You close `img` even if you didn't find any images and in this case `img` contains indetermined value.